# Como fazer um for em uma tag script?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, maps-javascript-api

Galera, estou tentando criar uma página em meu site que me mostre título, descrição e a localização do registro de algumas ocorrências. Quando acesso a página, carrego através de um `<c:forEach>` todas as ocorrências com seus devidos parâmetros. As ocorrências são enviadas dentro de uma lista via servlet para uma JSP, que as mostra.

Meu problema é que para carregar o mapa com a localização da ocorrência, preciso executar uma tag `<script>` que não possui corpo. A tag faz o carregamento dos arquivos e, no fim do carregamento, faz a chamada de uma função javascript, presente na página, utilizando um `callback="function()"`.

Por estar usando esta tag para carregar e chamar a função que mostra meu mapa com a localização da ocorrência, preciso que ele seja executado em um `forEach`, `for` ou qualquer outra coisa que me ajude a fazer o loop. Pensei em fazer com scriptlet ou JSTL, mas não consegui de imediato. Alguém pode me ajudar? Estou usando a API javascript do Google Maps.

JSP que realiza o carregamento da localização:

```html
    <%@page pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
            <%@include file="includes/cabecalho.html"%>
            <%@include file="includes/navmenu.jsp"%>
            <div class="centralizado jumbotron">
                <div class="card-deck">
                    <!--Panel-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <c:forEach var="ocorrencia" items="${ocorrencias}">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div style="padding: 10px;" class="card">
                                    <div style="padding: 10px;" class="card-body">
                                        <h5 class="card-title">${ocorrencia.tituloOcorrencia}</h5>
                                        <p class="card-text">${ocorrencia.descricaoOcorrencia}</p>
                                        <div style="position: relative; width: 100%;height: 300px" id="map"></div>
                                        <input type="number" id="lat" value="${ocorrencia.latitudeOcorrencia}" hidden/>
                                        <input type="number" id="lng" value="${ocorrencia.longitudeOcorrencia}" hidden/>
                                        <br>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-footer">
                                        <small class="text-muted">${ocorrencia.usuario_fk_ocorrencia.nomeUsuario} em ${ocorrencia.dataOcorrencia}</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script>
                // Initialize and add the map
                function initMap() {

                    //Attribuition for lat and lng to var
                    var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lat').value);
                    var lng = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lng').value);
                    // The location of Uluru
                    var uluru = {lat: parseFloat(lat), lng: parseFloat(lng)};
                    // The map, centered at Uluru
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(
                        document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 15, center: uluru});
                    // The marker, positioned at Uluru
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
                }
            </script>
            <!--Load the API from the specified URL
            * The async attribute allows the browser to render the page while the API loads
            * The key parameter will contain your own API key (which is not needed for this tutorial)
            * The callback parameter executes the initMap() function
            -->
            <!--Preciso do loop nesta tag-->
            <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAUWfu8L-5YIKUDXV812EM3tBZhrK0uDY4&callback=initMap"></script>

            <%@include file="includes/footer.jsp"%>
```

Algumas informações que podem ser úteis para me ajudar: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vê esse campo com os `id`s `lat`, `lng` e `map` dentro do `forEach`? Então, isso significa que você vai gerar diversos elementos com esses mesmos `id`s. No entanto, o valor do campo `id` deveria ser único.

A solução para tornar os `id`s únicos é concatenar um número após eles. E então, você pode usar esses números na função `initMap`.

Para obter um número único em cada iteração, você pode usar o campo `varStatus` do `forEach`.

Seu código deve ficar assim:

```html
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ include file="includes/cabecalho.html" %>
<%@ include file="includes/navmenu.jsp" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Initialize and add the map
    function initMap(n) {
        // Attribuition for lat and lng to var
        var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lat-' + n).value);
        var lng = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lng-' + n).value);
        var mapElement = document.getElementById('map-' + n);

        // The location of Uluru
        var uluru = {lat: parseFloat(lat), lng: parseFloat(lng)};
        // The map, centered at Uluru
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, {zoom: 15, center: uluru});
        // The marker, positioned at Uluru
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
    }
</script>
<div class="centralizado jumbotron">
    <div class="card-deck">
        <!--Panel-->
        <div class="row">
            <c:forEach var="ocorrencia" items="${ocorrencias}" varStatus="loop">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div style="padding: 10px;" class="card">
                        <div style="padding: 10px;" class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">${ocorrencia.tituloOcorrencia}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">${ocorrencia.descricaoOcorrencia}</p>
                            <div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 300px" id="map-${loop.index}"></div>
                            <input type="number" id="lat-${loop.index}" value="${ocorrencia.latitudeOcorrencia}" hidden/>
                            <input type="number" id="lng-${loop.index}" value="${ocorrencia.longitudeOcorrencia}" hidden/>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <small class="text-muted">${ocorrencia.usuario_fk_ocorrencia.nomeUsuario} em ${ocorrencia.dataOcorrencia}</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function initMap${loop.index}() {
                        initMap(${loop.index});
                    }
                </script>
                <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAUWfu8L-5YIKUDXV812EM3tBZhrK0uDY4&callback=initMap${loop.index}"></script>
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<%@ include file="includes/footer.jsp" %>
```

Observe que o `${loop.index}` vai virar um contador de iterações, e com ele, é possível carregar esse script do Google Maps uma vez para cada iteração.

O `loop` é uma variável do tipo [`javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagStatus`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html), um tipo de objeto que serve para fornecer dados sobre a iteração do `forEach`. um dos métodos dele é o [`getIndex()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html#getIndex--), que é o resultado da chamada à `${loop.index}`. Você pode ver mais sobre esse objeto [aqui](http://www.bmchild.com/2012/03/jstl-cforeach-varstatus-properties.html) e [nessa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18825950/540552).

Um outro detalhe: Recomendo utilizar UTF-8 ao invés de ISO-8859-1. O formato ISO-8859-1 é ultrapassado e obsoleto e vai te dar problemas quando alguém tentar colocar texto em chinês ou emojis na sua página. Melhor prevenir e mudar tudo para UTF-8 agora do que remediar depois quando começarem a aparecer problemas.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela a ajuda. O index do loop.index é algo como uma "variável reservada", certo?

Comment: @WelberDuarte Editei a resposta para explicar melhor isso.

Comment: Beleza. Valeu @VictorStafusa.